# Dynamic Checkbox with antd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd

I have a data and want to create checkboxes.

By default all fields should be checked and when I will uncheck one of the filed I should know which one is uncheked and update the filter data (remove unchecked field).

I'm using the ordinary checkbox but here I cant know which checkbox is checked or not.

I tried with checkboxgroup too but in the checkboxgroup you should define
Here is the
[Code example.](https://codesandbox.io/s/check-all-antd-5-0-7-forked-8bm54o?file=/demo.tsx)

```
https://codesandbox.io/s/check-all-antd-5-0-7-forked-8bm54o?file=/demo.tsx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to add a `checked` property to your data object, and use it instead of Checkbox's one, so simply import `useState()` from React and do as following:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./index.css";
import { Checkbox } from "antd";

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<any[]>([
    {
      id: 0,
      title: "User ID",
      key: "userId",
      checked: true
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "Description",
      key: "description",
      checked: true
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "Surname",
      key: "surname",
      checked: true
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "Name",
      key: "name",
      checked: true
    }
  ]);

  const onChange = (item) =>
    setData(data.map(e => e.id === item.id ? { ...e, checked: !item.checked } : e));

  return (
    <>
      {data.map((item) => (
        <Checkbox
          key={item.id}
          checked={item.checked}
          onChange={() => onChange(item)}
        >
          {item.title}
        </Checkbox>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Note that it's better to use your data's `id` as key in `map()` instead of `map()`'s index if you need to sort or modify your checkboxes' order, see more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Comment: Thank you, but why after filtering its not removing but inserting the unchecked data inside array?

Comment: When a checkbox change, I simply update your checkboxes list (data) with the checkbox list without the selected checkbox, and re-add it with the modified value (checked with the `!` to get it's reverse value). I find it quicker to remove and re-add it than finding the exact checkbox and edit it's properties

Comment: how can I uncheck the element without relocated its position? dont want to add unchecked at the end of the list, want to unchecked item to be at the same position as before? thanks

Comment: @user9832432 for that you can change the `onChange()` method like:
`setData(data.map(e => e.id === item.id ? { ...e, checked: !item.checked } : e))`
I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic example, which can give you more control

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 0,
    title: "User ID",
    key: "userId",
    checked: true
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Description",
    key: "description",
    checked: true
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Surname",
    key: "surname",
    checked: true
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Name",
    key: "name",
    checked: true
  }
];

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(data);

  const onChange = (item: any, e: CheckboxChangeEvent) => {
    console.log(`checked = ${e.target.checked}`, item);
    const checked = e.target.checked;
    setItems((checks) => {
      return checks?.map((e) => (e.id === item.id ? { ...e, checked } : e));
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      {items.map((item, i) => {
        return (
          <div key={i}>
            <Checkbox
              checked={item.checked}
              onChange={(e) => onChange(item, e)}
            >
              {item.title}
            </Checkbox>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};
```

Hope it helps