# defaultChecked on multiple mapped buttons and need to click twice to render

Tags: reactjs, radio-button

i'm mapping multiple buttons and want to select the 1st button to be checked on render and that value is shown on render

this is the axios get

```
const [productData, setProductData] = useState([]);
const [size, setSize] = useState([]);
const [choice, setChoice] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
const checkId = parseInt(window.location.href.slice(-1));
axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/products?id=${checkId}`)
.then((response) => {
setProductData(response.data[0]);
setSize(response.data[0].size);
setChoice(response.data[0].size[0].calories);
});
}, []);
```

here is the button map

```
const GetSize = () => {
    return size.map((val, i) => {
      return (
        <>
          <div>
            <input
              onClick={(e) => {
                setChoice(val.calories);
              }}
              defaultChecked={i == 0}
              type="radio"
            />
            <p>{val.option}</p>
            <p>{val.cup}</p>
          </div>
        </>
      );
    });
  };
```

and have to show a value on render here

```
 <div >
     <h1>{choice === 0 ? "" : choice}</h1
    <div>
       <h1>Size options</h1>
    </div>
    <div >
       <form>
          <GetSize />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

on render the {choice} doesn't show and only shown whenever i clicked on the radio button.

how do i make it so {choice} waits until setChoice runs

and also, the button needs to be clicked twice for it to be rendered chosen, but one click on the button is enough to make {choice} rendered

Comment: Did you try setting initial state `const [choice, setChoice] = useState(size?.[0]?.calories ?? 0)`

Comment: Please update the question with the code, it becomes easier to check

Comment: will do, edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

possible solution for the first part of the question

```
useEffect(() => {

   const checkId = parseInt(window.location.href.slice(-1));
   axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/products?id=${checkId}`)
   .then((response) => {
          setProductData(response.data?.[0] ?? []);
          const responseSize = response.data?.[0]?.size ?? []
          setSize(responseSize);
          // setting the default choice
          setChoice(responseSize.[0]?.calories ?? "")
   });

}, []);
```

Comment: this works and i updated the code in question, now the only problem is i need to click the radio button twice for it to be rendered

Comment: I was trying to think of the possible issues,  one reason could be if `GetSize` is defined inside another component, if its inside can you try moving it outside and passing it the size and setChoice props

Comment: will try to do that for now, what's weird is how the {choice} got set on 1 click but not rendered checked

Comment: `<input ` seems to be uncontrolled but that should not cause click twice to check issues, I was wondering if making them controlled can sort it out, I had answered on how to make [check components controlled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74809001/2122822), that may help in someway, [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/check-all-antd-5-0-7-forked-927euv?file=/demo.tsx) is the Codesandbox

Comment: i fixed the problem by adding ```const getCal = val.calories;``` and used it as a conditional inside the input

```checked={getCal === choice ? true : false}```

Comment: Glad you where able to sort it out, but do check if calories can be same other items, you might have to keep the checked index, Cheers mate

Comment: i checked it and its working properly, because of individual "getCal" in each mapped buttons. thank you